# Simple OData Client: Second level expands with untyped syntax

Tags: web-services, odata, expand

I am wondering is there a way to expand enteries with untyped syntax.

```
public class Entity
{
     public NavOne NavOne {get; set;}

}

public class NavOne
{
     public NavOne NavTwo {get; set;}
}
```

Like if you want to expand to second level you could do something like this:

```
var entity = await _client
.For<Entity>()
.Expand(x => x.NavOne.Select(y => y.NavTwo))
.FindEntriesAsync());
```

You could use to do it like this in V3:

```
var entity = (await _client
.For<Product>()
.Expand("NavOne.NavTwo")
.FindEntriesAsync());
```

But in V4 this does not work. Is there a way?

Comment: I use `.Expand("Navone($expand=NavTwo)")` syntax with Microsoft OData v4.  It may work for Simple Odata v4.

Comment: Supposing a "string NavOne.PropA" property exists, it sure does not work with .Expand("NavOne($select=PropA)") as simple.odata.client escapes the whole expand string with brackets: "[NavOne($select=PropA)]" so OData complains such an entity set does not exist.

Comment: HOWEVER, I just found out we can do the following: .Expand(x => x.NavOne).Select(x => x.NavOne.PropA). This isn't a direct answer to your question but should help, hence the comment :)

Comment: Didn't I mention that could be done in my question or am I not getting what you are saying?